# Serialize avro data using apache beam (KafkaIO.write)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-beam, flink-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

To publish data in avro format to kafka topic:

I am trying to build a generic record using AvroCoder and KafkaAvroSerializer . However, facing issues. Below is the code and error. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
   final public static TupleTag<GenericRecord> tag1 = new 
            TupleTag<GenericRecord>() {
    };

     public static final TupleTagList tagList = TupleTagList.of(tag2).and(tag3);

 PCollectionTuple mixedCollection =
                inputStream.apply("check", ParDo.of(new TransformAVRO()).
                        withOutputTags(tag1, tagList));

        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(
                getClass().getResourceAsStream("/schema.avsc"));
        AvroCoder<GenericRecord> genericCoder = AvroCoder.of(schema);

        PCollection<GenericRecord> testAvro = mixedCollection.
        get(tag2).setCoder(genericCoder);
```

**Error:**
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to return a default Coder for aadccheck.out2 [PCollection]. Correct one of the following root causes:
  No Coder has been manually specified;  you may do so using .setCoder().
  Inferring a Coder from the CoderRegistry failed: Unable to provide a Coder for org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord.
  Building a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.
  See suppressed exceptions for detailed failures.
  Using the default output Coder from the producing PTransform failed: PTransform.getOutputCoder called.

Comment: What is `TransformAVRO`? And last I checked, Beam already had a native Confluent Coder

Comment: It's a pardo function which has custom logic .

Comment: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIOTest.java#L424